# Extract data from table SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

What is the best way to achieve the scenario below;

We are extracting data from ten different files from ten different customers. we extract and load data into Database. the data is of the form code and description.
e.g.

```
Code  Description
   1      Cigrette
   2      Gift
   3      Bear
```

I want to extract only Gift items but the problem is The description for Gift can be different for different customers like Gift, GIFTCARD or GF etc. and code can also be different.

One way to solve the issue is by keeping a translation table for each customer but I want to avoid that as i do not want to enter code for every new customer.

`SOUNDEX()` in SQL seemed to be a good idea as well but it seems also not working perfectly.

How can i extract all the Gift items for all customers without keeping a translation table. please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: But how exactly do you draw the line that separates what to consider a gift and what not? SQL does not support mind-reading. You can try something like `Description LIKE 'G%F%'`, although that may produce false positives.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I ken thing is this, and this is proven design and pattern

```sql
-- Table: productType
id        int
desc      nvarchar

-- Table: productTypeExpanded
id         int
desc       nvarchar unique
prodTypeId int

-- Table: order
id         int
custId     int
desc       nvarchar -- I believe you're trying to identify product by this field

Select 
    p.desc,
    o.custId
From
    productType p inner join 
    productTypeExpanded e on p.id = e.prodTypeId inner join
    order o on o.desc = e.desc
```

Yea, you will have to enter all possible variations of whatever your customers use. But it can be ongoing process. You can pre-process file to search for unknown descriptions and add them accordingly.